# Zend_Db_Select with 'FOR XML PATH' for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to code the following query using Zend_Db_Select:

```
SELECT p1.SKU,
(
 SELECT ',' + Status
 FROM "Products" "p2"
 WHERE p2.SKU = p1.SKU
 ORDER BY "Status"
 FOR XML PATH ('')
)  AS "Statuses"
FROM "Products" p1
GROUP BY SKU
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$s1 = $products->select()
               ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
               ->from(array('p2' => 'Products'),
                      new Zend_Db_Expr("',' + Status")
                 )
               ->where('p2.SKU = p1.SKU')
               ->order('Status');

$s2 = $products->select()
               ->from(array('p1' => 'Products'),
                      array('p1.SKU',
                            'Statuses' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $s1 . ')')
                      )
                 )
               ->group('SKU');

echo $s2;
$dbRowSet = $Products->fetchAll($s2);
```

That gives me this:

```
SELECT "p1"."SKU",
(
 SELECT ',' + Status
 FROM "Products" AS "p2"
 WHERE (p2.SKU = p1.SKU)
 ORDER BY "Status" ASC
) AS "Statuses"
FROM "Products" AS "p1"
GROUP BY "SKU"
```

I can't figure out how to get the required `FOR XML PATH ('')`.

Also, isn't using the `.` operator with `$s1` calling `__toString()`, instead of leaving it as a native Zend_Db_Select object. Is there any other way to get the parens around `$s1`?

Alternatively, is there another way to do this whole query? I want to return each SKU and a concatenated grouping of all Statuses (a la `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL). The table is huge, so iterating over them in PHP takes an unacceptably long time.

Comment: Can you type out the relevant tables and fields?

Comment: @KSiimson, for the purposes of the question, there is a single 'Products' table with fields 'SKU' and 'Status'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was close, and with KSiimson's comments about string conversion in mind, this works:

```
$s1 = $products->select()
               ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
               ->from(array('p2' => 'Products'),
                      new Zend_Db_Expr("',' + Status")
                 )
               ->where('p2.SKU = p1.SKU')
               ->order('Status');

$s2 = $products->select()
               ->from(array('p1' => 'Products'),
                      array('p1.SKU',
                            'Statuses' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $s1 .
                                " FOR XML PATH(''))")
                      )
                 )
               ->group('SKU');

echo $s2;
$dbRowSet = $Products->fetchAll($s2);
```

This just concats the FOR XML PATH clause with the first query as a string. Not quite as elegant as I was hoping for, but "perfect is the enemy of good".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Zend Framework does not have a great support for constructing MS SQL specific queries. What you could do is use `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query()` and skip the object oriented query abstraction altogether. Alternatively, you could extend the `Zend_Db_Select`, add the appropriate code to `Zend_Db_Select::$_parts` and `Zend_Db_Select::_render*`, however you would still have an incomplete support.

I don't quite understand what exactly are you doing in the second code example, since the `$2` variable is not assigned at all.

Don't worry about the `__toString()` being called when you use `.` for string construction; the expression will ultimately be subjected to string conversion either way.

Comment: That's what I get for changing vars at the last minute for readability. I've fixed the second select() and added some clarifying code.